# What do you think of my choice (past simple or present perfect)

Tags: past-tense

I'm staying in my friend's house because we have made an house exchange.I am leaving tomorrow and I wrote a little note of what I had done during my stay.
Here it is

> Time to get back. I have very much enjoyed my stay. I have been 5 times in "Praha", each time  **(was/ have been**) great!Slappy was a nice place for swimming. I visited the Karlstein castle but (**I've preferred/ preferred**) the Cesky Steinberg  because they were not many people and my visit was in Italian.

Have I made good choices?

So I would choose **have been** great  because I still feel the memory of it with thrills and **I've preferred**  because it is my feeling now after visiting both castles.

Comment: Use simple past throughout. There's no good reason for using present perfect in the first case, and it's completely unidiomatic in the second (it's almost impossible to imagine a context where your past preference for the Cesky Steinberg has ***direct*** relevance to you and/or your circumstances at time of speaking/writing).

Comment: +1 on Past Indefinite.  Besides, "each time" is a very specific moment in time, so you can't but use Past because the moment is well-defined.

Comment: If I wrote all instead of each would be present perfect justified?

Comment: You mean "I have been 5 times to Praha, and *they all have been* great!", yes?  Sounds OK, I think.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't phrase it like that  in the first place "I visited the Karlstein castle but preferred..." because it sounds enigmatic.

In the second place I wouldn't use the perfect tenses. The problem is that the present perfect is grammatically redundant here as the things you talk about in the note happened in the past and there's no correlation between the present time and the past whatsoever. You used "have been in Praha" correctly because there's a correlation unlike in the other two cases.

I assume you're a non-native speaker and therefore I encourage you to read more examples of the rules you want to implement.

Comment: So that was my problem, the events I am referring to happened in the past and I used present perfect for enjoyed because my vacation was not fully finished.I thought that using present perfect made my note more "actual" because all the memories of this vacation are still strongly present and for me, it is  the correlation to the present . Should I have used past simple for all verbs including" I went five times in Praha and it was great."?